# Twitter emoticons in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, emoticons

I'm re-writing my sentiment analysis script in python 3. I need to split the data based on the emoticons in the text. In python 2, I could just look for text emoticons like ":)" for example. However, in python 3 I am getting much less text emoticons and much more actual emoticons like:

```
I'm so excited to see what my future holds
```

That empty square at the end is actually an emoticon graphic. Instead of in Python 2x:

```
I'm so excited to see what my future holds :)
```

Question is, how do I handle these graphic emoticons? What are they? If unicode, what are some of the common encodings so that I can extract data with these graphic emoticons.

FYI, this is how I was doing it in python 2x

```
happy_set = set([":)",":-)","=)"])
sad_set = set([":(",":-(","=("])

happy = [tweet.split() for tweet in tweet_list for face in happy_set if face in tweet]
sad = [tweet.split() for tweet in tweet_list for face in sad_set if face in tweet]
```

Comment: Try printing the character code for that character. (You will find it *is* a valid Unicode code. They can all be found in unicode.org's tables.)

Comment: Example of what you are talking about would be nice

Comment: [Unicode for emoticons](http://www.google.com/search?q=unicode+emoticons+list&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari)

Comment: Or http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F600.pdf